# Composição de objetos em javascript

Tags: javascript, composição, objetos

Estou estudando um pouco mais de javascript aqui e cheguei a um problema:

Tenho um objeto chamado player:

```
let Player = function () {
    this.name = 'player';
}

Player.prototype = new Sprite();
Player.prototype = new Shape2D();
```

Seria isso que eu tento fazer, e não funciona, porque o javascript por meio do prototype só aceita uma objeto herdado, e no exemplo acima atribuo as duas a prototype. Se tentarmos chamar assim, sendo "box.x" uma propriedade de Shape2D:

```
console.log(Player.boxX);
```

Recebo um "undefined". Então pensei, não quero usar herança nessa situação, e como não gosto de criar escadinha de herança, prefiro tentar achar outras alternativas. Pesquisei e vi sobre composição, mas ainda não entendo como seria em javascript, penso assim:

```
let Player = function () {
    this.name = 'player';
    this.sprite = new Sprite();
    this.shape2D = new Shape2D();
}
```

ou

```
let Player = function () {
    this.name = 'player';
}

Player.prototype.sprite = new Sprite();
Player.prototype.shape2d = new Shape2D();
```

ou

```
let Sprite = {x:0, y:0}; 
let Shape2D = {x:0, y:0, width:0, height:0};
let Player = Object.assign(Sprite, Shape2D); // Sendo Sprite e Shape2D agora objetos literais
```

como fazer isso de um jeito mais limpo possível?

```
obj1 = new Player();
obj2 = new Player();
```

O obj1 seria igual ao obj2? preciso de uma maneira em que os objetos sejam diferentes, que não aconteça de eu mudar algo no objeto sprite de um e acabe mudando no outro por ter apenas referenciado. Eu teria que clonar os objetos para criar essa composição?

Answer (score 0):

Estava a estudar até agora, e encontrei a maneira de escrever e resolver o problema que considero mais agradavel para mim:

```
const Sprite = (x=0, y=0) => ({
  x: x,
  y: y
});

const Shape2D = (x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0) => ({
  x: x,
  y: y,
  width: width,
  height: height
});

const spritePlayer = Sprite(0, 0);
const shape2DPlayer = Shape2D(0, 0, 32, 32);

let Player = Object.assign({}, spritePlayer, shape2DPlayer);
```